# Eclipse: Blacklist types from code completion

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to blacklist certain types from consideration in Eclipse's code completion?

For example, I use Google Collection's `com.google.common.collect.Lists` class quite often.  What I will do is type "Lists" then Ctrl-space and select a method (like `newArrayList()`) and Eclipse will add the import statements automatically.  But one annoying thing is that TestNG has the same identical class with a different package name `org.testng.v6.Lists` and often I will select the TestNG version by mistake.

Is there a way to "blacklist" `org.testng.v6.Lists` from consideration in code completion so I don't import it by mistake?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can set up Type Filters to do this. See the section "Suppress types in content assist" [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html) for more information.

Here are some screen shots for posterity:

Open the preferences dialog and go to Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters:

[image: Type Filter Preferences]

Click the "Add..." button:

[image: Add Type Filter Dialog]

Now it should appear in the Filter list:

[image: New Type Filter Added]